# Server side rendering a single component in a multi page laravel application

Tags: laravel, vue.js, server-side-rendering, vue-ssr

I'm building a laravel application, the notifications in my navbar is a vueJS component.

```
   <notifications-dropdown></notifications-dropdown>
   <li class="nav-item">
         <a href="{{ url('my-courses') }}" class="nav-link nav-hover">دوراتي</a>
   </li>
```

I need to server side render the notifications component and honestly I have no idea where to start, all resources are for rendering a full SPA and not a single component.
I'm using https://github.com/spatie/laravel-server-side-rendering for SSR.